# How to fix "SCRIPT1002:syntax error" export in IE 11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, es6-modules

I use web components, export default and *.mjs

My code looks like this. It is index.bundle.mjs and html file.
In code *.mjs i do export default

```
export default () =>{

    console.log('test')
}
```

In code *.html i include index.bundle.mjs

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang=ru xml:lang=ru>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#cdfecc">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,minimum-scale
</head>
<body>
<noscript>Включите java script</noscript>
<div id="input"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.bundle.mjs"></script></body>
</html>
```

In IE 11 i  get error `script1002: syntax error.`

How can i include this syntax in IE 11 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`export` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Browser_compatibility) and `=>` [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) are ECMAScript 6 syntax which is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=es6) by IE. You should transpile your code to ES5 to make it work in IE.

If you require ES6 features in Internet Explorer 11, check out a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Here's [an article](https://medium.com/@SunnyB/how-to-convert-es6-into-es5-using-babel-1b533d31a169) about how to use babel to convert ES6 into ES5, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

We can fix this error by modifying the configuration in webpack. Basically this is because of arrow function and restructuring is not being handled properly by IE.

```
output: {

        filename: "name.js",
        environment: {
              arrowFuction: false, 
              destructuring: false
        },
 }
```